# Start reading from specific offset in ksql?

Tags: ksqldb

I can say that i want to start reading from "earliest" or "latest" or "none", but i would like to know if it is possible to start a query from a specific offset. EG:

```
select * from test-stream offset 1000
```

or via ksql settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **KSQL does not currently support that feature.**
Checkout below github issue.

[KSQL Github issue : Additional pseudo-columns for OFFSET and PARTITION](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/976)

Comment: That issue, whilst useful, does not address what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that currently. KSQL only supports `earliest` or `latest` offset.

Answer (score 0):

[From version 0.23.1](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/pull/8245) is now possible to use the ROWOFFSET header to achieve this. Read more about the feature [klip50](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/blob/master/design-proposals/klip-50-partition-and-offset-in-ksqldb.md).

Something like this should do the work:

```
SELECT * FROM my_stream WHERE ROWOFFSET > 12 EMIT CHANGES;
```

In the same release they introduced ROWPARITION as well in the headers:

```
SELECT * FROM my_stream WHERE ROWPARTITION = 0 AND ROWOFFSET > 12 EMIT CHANGES;
```